# Multi inheritance with Graph db in SQL

Tags: sql-server, charts

I would like to solve the following problem with SQL Server graphs.

I have a table with classes in a graph table (as Node). These can be combined arbitrarily (as Edge).
Each class has a set of attributes. They are currently in a normal table.

What do I want to achieve?

A-> B

If I connect classes A and B via the graph, I want a list of all attributes of the connected classes (in this case all attributes of classes A and B).

A -> B -> C

If I then add class C, I also want the attributes of classes A and B and C.
etc.

Comment: Please provide a complete [mre] with sample data, desired results and your attempt.

Comment: Not sure what's stopping you, have you looked at how to traverse a graph relation? you just need to join the attributes tables for all the tables in the "path". Although, i'm not sure inheritance is best modelled as graph table but it can work.

Comment: traverse a graph was a good hint. Thanks

Comment: according to the instructions of shortest_path it only finds the shortest paths. It does not find all of them. Therefore the approach with the graph database does not work. Change it to hierarchies